# Prompt for value to store in env variable

Tags: shell, environment-variables, password

I'd like to store a value in an environment variable, but I don't want to do it like this `VAR_NAME=secretvalue`, because then it will be stored in the shell's history file. Is there a way to prompt me for the value, just like `passwd` does?

Comment: Seems related: [Is there any way to keep a command from being added to your history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6094/is-there-any-way-to-keep-a-command-from-being-added-to-your-history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the password in the clipboard, use `xsel` or `xclip` or `pbpaste`. See [Any function copying from clipboard to a variable in Bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424295/any-function-copying-from-clipboard-to-a-variable-in-bash)

Otherwise, assuming that the secret value doesn't contain any newlines (or any control characters or characters that you can't type):

```
printf 'Password: '
IFS= read -r VAR_NAME
```

Many shells let you pass the prompt directly to `read`:

```
IFS= read -p 'Password: ' -r VAR_NAME
```

If you don't want the secret to be visible on your terminal, see [Reading passwords without showing on screen in Bash Scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35088/reading-passwords-without-showing-on-screen-in-bash-scripts). Note that even without this, the password won't be saved anywhere once you clear your terminal.